# Python refuses text.replace() in one environment

Tags: python, apache, replace, pylons

I've been mocking about with the following bit of dirty support-code for a pylons app, which works *fine* in a python-shell, a separate python file, or when running in paster. Now, we've put the application on-line through mod_wsgi and apache and this specific piece of code stopped working completely. First off, the code itself:

```
def fixStyle(self, text):
    t = text.replace('<p>', '<p style="%s">' % (STYLEDEF,))
    t = t.replace('class="wide"', 'style="width: 125px; %s"' % (STYLEDEF,))
    t = t.replace('<td>', '<td style="%s">' % (STYLEDEF,))
    t = t.replace('<a ', '<a style="%s" ' % (LINKSTYLE,))
    return t
```

It seems pretty straightforward, and to be honest, it is. So what happens when I put a piece of text in it, for example:

```
<table><tr><td>Test!</td></tr></table>
```

The output should be:

```
<table><tr><td style="stuff-from-styledef">Test!</td></tr></table>
```

and it is, on most systems. When we put it through the app on Apache/mod_wsgi though, the following happens:

```
<table><tr><td>Test!</td></tr></table>
```

You guessed it.

I have put logging at the start outputting the text, and at the end outputting original text and the t variable. It displays what I present here: on most systems t is changed, on the apache environment it isn't.

Of course I made sure to restart apache (to get it to reload the .py files) after every change, and it reflected in the logging output.

I'm currently at a loss and have no idea where to go next. Googling doesn't really work out, so I'm hoping on you guys to help out and perhaps point out a fundamental issue with using whatever-is-causing-this.

If anything is missing I'll edit it in.

Comment: Well...Are you sure apache is using the right version of the file?

Comment: I wonder if you could show the text value with something like debug(text) at the begining of the function and debug(t) at the end of the function. I suspect the problem is not here

Comment: I added the text and t values to logging (log.info([text, t, text==t])) and nothing changed.

Comment: did you write it just before the return and what is written in your logs?

Comment: Yes, I did, at start and end. Both output exactly the same. I'll add it to the original question in a bit.

Comment: You said "I have put logging at the start outputting the text, and at the end outputting original text and the t variable. " but you did not log in the function. I suppose the problem is in the way you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Add some print statments and examine the Apache logs:

```
def fixStyle(self, text):
    print "text:", text
    print "STYLEDEF", STYLEDEF
    t = text.replace('<p>', '<p style="%s">' % (STYLEDEF,))
    print "t:", t
```

Comment: As noted in the comments and now also in the original post, I of course added logging to test out what's going on. But I removed it for brevity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea concerning what is your problem, but I find the repetition of `replace()` not a good thing: if the four patterns are in the string, there will be 4 times creation of a new string.

IMO, this should be better:

```
def fixStyle(self, text):
    t = text.replace('<p>', '<p style="%s">' % (STYLEDEF,))
    t = t.replace('class="wide"', 'style="width: 125px; %s"' % (STYLEDEF,))
    t = t.replace('<td>', '<td style="%s">' % STYLEDEF)
    t = t.replace('<a ', '<a style="%s" ' % (LINKSTYLE,))
    return t

import re

STYLEDEF = 'stuff-from-styledef'
LINKSTYLE = 'VVVV'

def aux(m, dic = {'<p':('<p style="',STYLEDEF),
                  '<td':('<td style="',STYLEDEF),
                  'class="wide"':('style="width: 125px; ',STYLEDEF),
                  '<a':('<a style="',LINKSTYLE)} ):

    return '%s%s"' % dic[m.group()]

pat = re.compile('<p(?=>)>|class="wide"|<td(?=>)|<a(?= )')

ch = '<table><tr><td>Test!</td></tr></table><a type="brown" >'
print ch
print fixStyle(None, ch)
print pat.sub(aux,ch)
```

result

```
<table><tr><td>Test!</td></tr></table><a type="brown" >
<table><tr><td style="stuff-from-styledef">Test!</td></tr></table><a style="VVVV" type="brown" >
<table><tr><td style="stuff-from-styledef">Test!</td></tr></table><a style="VVVV" type="brown" >
```

I think `re.sub()` does the replacements in only one pass upon the string.

Defining  parameter **dic** with a default argument => the value is assigned to **dic** at the definition of **aux()** and then doesn't change anymore. At each call, there is no passing of an argument to **dic** from the outer level: the value is kept inside the function.

Also, the function **aux()** doesn't need to go out and search the values of STYLEDEF and LINKSTYLE ouside the function.

All that should  increase the execution speed.

.

EDIT:
Since  `' style="'` and **STYLEDEF** are common to several results to be returned, I had tried to shorten the list of them and I had found

```
def aux(m, dic = {'<p'          :'<p style="%s"',
                  '<td'         :'<td style="%s"',
                  'class="wide"':'style="width: 125px; %s"'} ):
    if m.group(1):
        return '<a style="%s"' % LINKSTYLE
    else:
        return dic[m.group()] % STYLEDEF

pat = re.compile('<p(?=>)|class="wide"|<td(?=>)|(<a)(?= )')
```

In the aim to take down the conditional lines , I wrote the preceding solution and, I dont know why, I stopped there. The interest of the solution was in the writing of the Regular Expression string , with assertions, that allow to write the solution of John Machin, but I polluted it with these oafish tuples.

There is also this solution:

```
def aux(m, STY = STYLEDEF,LIN = LINKSTYLE ):
    return ( 'style="width: 125px; ' if m.group(3) else m.group(1)+' style="' ) + \
           ( LIN if m.group(2) else STY) + '"'   

pat = re.compile('(<p(?=>)|<td(?=>)|(<a(?= )))|(class="wide")')
```

But the clearer and simpler solution is, as John Machin noticed:

```
def aux(m, dic = {'<p' :'<p style="%s"' % STYLEDEF,
                  '<td':'<td style="%s"' % STYLEDEF,
                  '<a' :'<a style="%s"' % LINKSTYLE,
                  'class="wide"':'style="%s"' % ('width: 125px; '+STYLEDEF) } ):
    return dic[m.group()] 

pat = re.compile('<p(?=>)|class="wide"|<td(?=>)|<a(?= )')
```

The values in **dic** are calculated only at the execution of the function **aux()**'s definition.

In fact , it's very near the arguments of the `replace()` functions.

Comment: Why don't you concatenate the doodads at `aux` definition time? `dic` values become e.g. `'<p style=' + STYLEDEF + '"'` instead of `('<p style="',STYLEDEF)` and all aux needs to do is `return dic[m.group()]`

Comment: @John Machin You know: my flickering brain.... You are perfectly right. See my edit. By the way, isn't it _doodah_ , with h ?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/doodad and http://www.thefreedictionary.com/doodah

Comment: I do agree on the fact that 4 replaces following each other is nasty, but it _is_ dirty code. Also, it's the simplest code I could think off. I am not sure how making the code more complicated will solve it.

Nonetheless! I shall attempt to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but: Descriptions of debugging that don't mention `repr()` are not credible. Ensure that you are logging `repr(text)` and `repr(t)`, NOT `text` and `t`.

Run the non-working environment and at least one of the working environments on the same piece of data and edit your question to show the actual code that you used and the actual logging output.